# Shouldn't there be a tomb-raider tag along with tag for each of title of the series

Tags: discussion, tags

I see for each of the tomb-raider franchise title there is a tag. But there is not general tag for tomb-raider. like [tomb-raider](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomb-raider). I didn't find this tag exists. It'd be very helpful for people who just follow [tomb-raider](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomb-raider), someone like me.

Answer (score 4):

You can always add [tomb-raider*] and/or [*tomb-raider] to your favourites - the stars would then mean anything that started with or ended with "tomb-raider" in the tag would show up in your favourite questions list.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/td1TB.jpg